# ggplot2: remove blank space for weekends and holidays from x-axis dates

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

running into issues while plotting stock data in ggplot2 and with an x-axis that contains gaps from weekends and holidays. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169366/r-ggplot2-how-to-hide-missing-dates-from-x-axis) post has been very helpful, but i run into a variety of issues when trying to use ordered factors.

```
library(xts)
library(grid)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(bdscale)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("SPY", from = Sys.Date() - 1460, to = Sys.Date(), adjust = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE)

input <- data.frame(SPY["2015/"])
names(input) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")

# i've tried changing rownames() to index(), and the plot looks good, but the x-axis is inaccurate
# i've also tried as.factor()
xaxis <- as.Date(rownames(input)) 
input$xaxis <- xaxis

p <- ggplot(input)
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis, xend = xaxis, y = Low, yend = High), size = 0.50)           # body
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis - 0.4, xend = xaxis, y = Open, yend = Open), size = 0.90)    # open
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis, xend = xaxis + 0.4, y = Close, yend = Close), size = 0.90)  # close
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(scale_y_log10())
p + ggtitle("SPY: 2015")
```

[image]

The plot above (sans red boxes) is generated with the above code segment. And the following charts are some of the issues when attempting some solutions. First, if I try using the data frame's index, I will generate I nice looking graph, but the x-axis is inaccurate; the data currently ends in October, but in the plot below it ends in July:
[image]

```
xaxis <- as.Date(index(input))
```

Second, if I try coercing the rownames to an ordered factor, I lose my horizontal tick data (representing the open and the close).
[image]

```
xaxis <- factor(rownames(input), ordered = TRUE)
```

The same issue of removing the horizontal ticks happens if I use the package bdscale, but the gridlines are cleaner:

[image]

```
p <- p + scale_x_bd(business.dates = xaxis)
```

Comment: In your question above, what is inaccurate about the X-axis produced in "The plot above (sans red boxes)"?

Comment: the red boxes highlight the gaps in the x-axis that i want to remove. i want a plot that looks like the second plot (no gaps), but with the x-axis of the first plot

Comment: So then, the problem the automated identification of what dates are holidays or weekends, since if you did that you can subset `input` to retain only work days, right?

Comment: well, if you inspect the data, there is no weekend or holiday present in the series. there are simply just gaps. input already retains only the work days

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to use `bdscale` for this, just tell it to use more gridlines:

```
ggplot(input) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis, xend = xaxis, y = Low, yend = High), size = 0.50) +           # body 
  geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis - 0.4, xend = xaxis, y = Open, yend = Open), size = 0.90) +    # open
  geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis, xend = xaxis + 0.4, y = Close, yend = Close), size = 0.90)  + # close
  ggtitle("SPY: 2015") +
  xlab('') + ylab('') +
  scale_x_bd(business.dates=xaxis, max.major.breaks=10, labels=date_format("%b '%y")) # <==== !!!!
```

[image]

It should put October on the axis there, but it's not that smart. Womp womp. Pull requests welcome!

Comment: thanks dave! in addition to the last x-axis tick, it appears that your implementation removed the open and close horizontal ticks that i am trying preserve.

Comment: ya i see what you mean. the way `bdscale` works is it translates your dates into the indexes into your date array; it's a fake continuous scale, there aren't any fractions. the `geom_vline` allows you to circumvent the axis scaling, let me see if there's a way for `geom_segment` to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

The method below uses faceting to remove spaces between missing dates, then removes white space between facets to recover the look of an unfaceted plot.

First, we create a grouping variable that increments each time there's a break in the dates (code adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21529560/496488)). We'll use this later for faceting.

```
input$group = c(0, cumsum(diff(input$xaxis) > 1))
```

Now we add the following code to your plot. `facet_grid` creates a new facet at each location where there was a break in the date sequence due to a weekend or holiday. `scale_x_date` adds major tick marks once per week and minor grid lines for each day, but you can adjust this. The `theme` function gets rid of the facet strip labels and the vertical spaces between facets:

```
p + facet_grid(. ~ group, space="free_x", scales="free_x") +
  scale_x_date(breaks=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"),max(input$xaxis), "1 week"), 
               minor_breaks="1 day",
               labels=date_format("%b %d, %Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, size=11),
        panel.margin = unit(-0.05, "lines"),
        strip.text=element_text(size=0),
        strip.background=element_rect(fill=NA)) +
  ggtitle("SPY: 2015")
```

Here's the resulting plot. The spaces for weekends and holidays are gone. The major breaks mark each week. I set the weeks in the`scale_x_date` `breaks` argument to start on a Thursday since none of the holidays fell on a Thursday and therefore each facet has a major tick mark for the date. (In contrast, the default breaks would fall on a Monday. Since holidays often fall on a Monday, weeks with Monday holidays would not have a major tick mark with the default breaks.) Note, however, that the spacing between the major breaks inherently varies based on how many days the market was open that week.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to treat the dates as discrete values rather than continuous.  This approach with a slightly simplified version of your code might look like:

```
getSymbols("SPY", from = Sys.Date() - 1460, to = Sys.Date(), adjust = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE)
SPY <- SPY["2015/"]
colnames(SPY) <- sub("SPY.","", colnames(SPY))
month_brks <- c(1,endpoints(SPY, "months")[-1])

p <- ggplot(data.frame(xaxis=seq(nrow(SPY)), SPY))
p <- p + geom_linerange(aes(x=xaxis, ymin=Low, ymax=High), size=.5)
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x = xaxis,  y = Open), size = 4., label="-", hjust=.7, vjust=0)  # Open
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x = xaxis,  y = Close), size = 4., label="-", hjust=-.1, vjust=0)  # close
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=month_brks, labels=format(index(SPY)[month_brks], "%d %b %Y"))
p <- p + labs(title="SPY: 2015", x="Date", y="Price")
```

UPDATE

Updated treatment of axis labels.

Comment: this is great, thank you! i'll have to play around with the axis labels

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can tweak it manually, but it's kind of hacky. First, you should use index, so that your observations are numbered 1 to 188.

```
   input$xaxis <-index(as.Date(rownames(input)))
```

Then your own plot code:

```
p <- ggplot(input)
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis, xend = xaxis, y = Low, yend = High), size = 0.50)           # body
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis - 0.4, xend = xaxis, y = Open, yend = Open), size = 0.90)    # open
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = xaxis, xend = xaxis + 0.4, y = Close, yend = Close), size = 0.90)  # close
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(scale_y_log10()) + ggtitle("SPY: 2015")
```

And finally, I looked in input where the breaks should be made, and supplied the labels manually:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=input$xaxis[c(1,62,125,188)], labels=c("jan","apr","jul","oct"))
```

NOTE HERE that I was lazy and just took the closest date for 1-jan, 1-apr 1-jul and 1-oct, because 1 jan is a holiday, the label "jan" stands below 2-jan. And I put the label "oct" below below 30-sep, the last entry in `input`. You can off course adjust this as you wish.

Off course, you could automate the label add a label field with date and extract the month.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't been able to get the OHLC to work - think you'd need a custom `geom`.

I know it isn't exactly what you asked for, but may I tempt you with a delicious candle chart instead?

```
library(dplyr)
library(bdscale)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
library(magrittr)
library(scales)

getSymbols("SPY", from = Sys.Date() - 1460, to = Sys.Date(), adjust = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE)

input <- data.frame(SPY["2015/"]) %>% 
  set_names(c("open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adjusted")) %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(rownames(.)))

input %>% ggplot(aes(x=date, ymin=low, ymax=high, lower=pmin(open,close), upper=pmax(open,close), 
                     fill=open<close, group=date, middle=pmin(open,close))) + 
  geom_boxplot(stat='identity') +
  ggtitle("SPY: 2015") +
  xlab('') + ylab('') + theme(legend.position='none') +
  scale_x_bd(business.dates=input$date, max.major.breaks=10, labels=date_format("%b '%y"))
```

[image]