# How do I get the dates to render correctly in a ggplot using the 'bdscale' package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I successfully removed unwanted dates in a plot using the 'bdscale' packaget that were causing a known smooth curve to render in a jagged fashion due to weekends and holidays being accounted for on the x-axis.  See [ggplot2: remove blank space for weekends and holidays from x-axis dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893176/ggplot2-remove-blank-space-for-weekends-and-holidays-from-x-axis-dates).  However, now my Dates no longer render correctly.  I am certain there is an easy fix, but the solution escapes me.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

The csv file is located at my github site https://github.com/123blee/123blee.github.io/blob/main/data1.csv and I call the dataframe 'xxx' in the code.

[image]

```
library(plotly)
library(bdscale)
library(scales)

# Data file - https://github.com/123blee/123blee.github.io/blob/main/data1.csv
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893176/ggplot2-remove-blank-space-for-weekends-and-holidays-from-x-axis-dates
  
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(data = xxx, aes(x = Date)) + 
      geom_line(aes(y = a), color = "blue") + 
      geom_line(aes(y = b), color="black") +
      theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="white", size=0.2)) +
      scale_x_bd(business.dates=xxx$Date, max.major.breaks=10) +  
      ylim( 10, 25 )  
    
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I deciphered the issue.  The 'xxx' tibble's Date column was in 'dttm' format.  Adding the below single line of fixed the issue.

```
xxx$Date <- as.Date(xxx$Date)
```

[image]