# using factors to order ggplot x axis dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have a data.frame `df`

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

day.start = today()

df = data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = today() - days(10), to = today() + days(10), 'day'))
df$day.idx = as.numeric(df$date - day.start + 1)
df$day.idx = ifelse(df$day.idx < 1, df$day.idx + nrow(df), df$day.idx)
df = df %>% arrange(day.idx)            
df$value = 1:nrow(df)
```

I can plot the values vs dates like this

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value))
```

However I want to make an adjustment for a custom year so I want the x axis to start at today's date.

```
## I want the x axis to start with day.start
df = df %>% mutate(date = factor(date, levels = as.character(df$date)))

## how to change x axis to behave like dates again?
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value)) ## where is this line?
```

So the second plot looks better but how do I format the x-axis to look like (nicely spaced) dates again?

[image: for]

Comment: the function `today()` is from the `lubridate` package, don't forget that for your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26611593/5319229

Turns out it has nothing to do with factors.

The [bdscale](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bdscale/bdscale.pdf) package came in handy.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

day.start = today()

df = data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = today() - days(10), to = today() + days(10), 'day'))
df$day.idx = as.numeric(df$date - day.start + 1)
df$day.idx = ifelse(df$day.idx < 1, df$day.idx + nrow(df), df$day.idx)
df = df %>% arrange(day.idx)            
df$value = 1:nrow(df)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value, group = 1))+
  bdscale::scale_x_bd(business.dates = df$date, labels = scales::date_format('%b %d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code as is, I get the following message:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

So `ggplot` doesn't know to "connect the dots", this is why the message mentions *adjusting the group aesthetic*. To combat this, I assigned 1 to gorup.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach because your dates are then out of order, as can be seen if we adjust your x-axis text:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**Edit:**
I'd recommend keeping your `date` field as a date, and using `filter` to keep only the observations you want before piping into ggplot:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(date)) %>% 
  filter(date >= today()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date()
```

[image]

Comment: ideally as a `Date` so I can have custom `breaks`

Comment: I'm interested in the whole field. The filter drops observations.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[df$date > today(), ] %>% 
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

---

EDIT: An option would be to use `filter` rather than `df[df$date > today(), ]`(check @OTStats's answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the x-axis to stay in the same order as in your example, and you just want it to be readable, I recommend changing the angle of the text:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = value), group = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value), group = 1) +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: What if you have 100s more points on the x-axis? This only works if you have few.